# message creation using php

Tags: php, mysql

please help i am making a message box which allows user to send message to each which will be stored in database.
  my problem is while inserting new message it successfully inserts to my database.but while printing the values from my database it prints the previously inserted message first..but i need to be print newly added message.

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM MESSAGES WHERE ID='9996565'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    echo $row['message'];
}
?>
```

while printing $row['message'] i need to print recently added message first pls help me!!!

Comment: What did you try? By the way, what you need is the SQL `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: You have to order them! just like what @Amal suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control this using [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) clause in your SQL query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM MESSAGES ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");
```

The above example will fetch all the entries in reverse order, and `echo $row['message'];` message would display the last entry first. You can change the query according to your needs, but that's what you basically need.

Comment: And "LIMIT 1" should appended to this query!

Comment: am adding all users message in one table am printing to them using their id hence how to find their newly added msgs..to a particular usr